# Git merge to ignore few lines of code in a file

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

While doing a Git merge I am getting conflicts for some common version changes.
for example, I have shell script like this below :

```
#! /bin/bash
# author : Anil
# version : 1.2
echo "Hello world"
XXXXXX
XXXXXX
```

There  is a parameter version  in comments section. This parameter is always updated and I want git to ignore this line during merging.
How can I achieve this i.e. make Git to ignore few common lines in few files like this.

regards,
Anil

Comment: Why you dont want to merge the version comment?

Comment: I know it's not your question, but I'd ask why you need this comment block at all? You're using Git. Git's pretty good at versioning without you needing to do it yourself too :)

Comment: Hi,  Its the developers who write the code .. so this is the Organisation standard for every shell script needs to have things like version, author, date modified etc in comments section. So the other automation have a requirement that  during  git merge from one branch to another, it should ignore such comments